# Ratchet + Symfony3: how to get access to current server from outside

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, symfony-3.4

Here is my Symfony3 command that I'm using for websocket server purpose

```
    public function __construct(ChatFlowProcessor $chatManager, int $webSocketPort)
    {
        $this->chatManager = $chatManager;
        $this->webSocketPort = $webSocketPort;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                $this->chatManager
            )
        ),
        $this->webSocketPort
    );
    $server->run();
```

As you see, I've got a `chatManager` simply using Symfony3 autowiring. The service implements Ratchet `MessageComponentInterface`.

Now, I want to get access to the server from outside of the connection. I mean, send a message to websocket client using my `chatManager`, apparently I need to get access to `chatManager` instance, that stored in WsServer and keep information about all active connections.

Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need an access to chatManager just to send messages. It's a chat server which only purpose IS to transfer messages from/to all its clients.

Simply create a websocket client, connect it to your server (together other clients) and start sending (and receiving) messages. Any special functionality (e.g. send message to one client only or get list of all clients etc.) must be implemented in chatManager (Ratchets MessageComponentInterface).

Perhaps I misunderstood the question, sorry then.

Comment: I think I got what you mean, I really keep all the chat-related functionality in chatManager, but now I have a special behavior when a `Symfony` user being deleted, and I need to describe a behavior for my chat app, I have a problem to spot that event.

Comment: Check chat users against Symfony users in chatManager -> onMessage. If one is removed from Symfony then close his chat connection.